# how can I know if the user has left the page in wicket?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, wicket, wicket-1.5

I am searching for a way to know when the user leaves the page and has not saved the changes then show wicket's modal(preferable but could be a confirmation box).

Additional info:
the solution should have  minimal effects in  code, because I have about 30 pages that will have the behavior, actually all my web pages extends from one called LayoutPage, something similar to [this](http://wicket.apache.org/learn/examples/markupinheritance.html)

I tried with pure JavaScript solution like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own) question, but the application send a lot of data via AJAX requests, so I couldn't determine a nice way to know if the data has been sent to the server

Ihen I start to look in the source code of the `Form.class` of Wicket. It has a nice method called `isSubmitted()`; I could use it if I was able to know from wicket if the user is about to quit the page.

I don't want to write a validation for each page in the system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply generate your browser onbeforeunload using https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/calling-wicket-from-javascript.html. In the callback you can then check the state of your form or page.